# Is there a connection between kushits and kushans?

Tags: india, ancient-egypt, bronze-age, migration

I've noticed a resemblance in tribe names. I know that the [Kingdom of Kush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kingdom_of_Kush) and the [Kushan Empire](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kushan_Empire) are divided not only by a substantial distance but also a substantial amount of time. Is there any reason to believe that there is a relationship between two tribes?

Comment: Resemblance of tribe names? Which tribes is your question referring to?

Answer (score 3):

No, there isn't. What you have here is a *coincidence*. There are only so many sounds that the human voice finds easy to use in language, so similar names come up in different language groups.

Language groups also reveal the lack of connection between the two "Kush" groups. The Kingdom of Kush was Nubian, speaking Afro-Asiatic and Nilo-Saharan languages. The Kushan Empire spoke Indo-European languages. This is strong evidence against an ethnic connection, which the distance in both space and time made very implausible to start with.

Comment: a) Afro-Asiatic and Indo-European are supposed by several hypothesis to be related by a parent language family and, while these theories have been heavily contested and did not produce a system of highly regular sound correspondances, there is no competing theory other than deus ex machina de novo. (a continuous sound-law isn't strictly expected from the power of a few researchers set versus the power of an immense tempo-spatial frame of reference, as well as substrate language corruption, etc). b) The time difference is difficult, nigh impossible, indeed. However ...